# PHP maze-generator with Looping

Tags: php

i have problem about create maze-generator

i have variable $num = 5, and i want output like this :

```
@ @@@
@   @
@@@ @
@   @
@ @@@
```

i already trying to solve my problem and the output like this :

```
@ @@@
@   @
@@@ @
@   @
@@@ @
```

how to make output correct like i want first? I already write scipt on php like this :

```
<?php

$num        = 5;
$space      = $num - 2;
$end        = $num - 1;
$left       = true;
$mid        = false;
$right      = false;
$leftCount  = 1;
$rightCount = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++)
    {
        if ($left) {
            $line = ($i % 2 == 0 && $j == 1) ? "&nbsp;&nbsp; ":" 1 ";

            ($j == $end) ? $left = false:$mid = true;
            $leftCount  = 0;
            $rightCount = 1;

            echo $line;
        }
        else if ($mid)
        {
            $line = (($i % 2 == 1 && $j == 0) || ($i % 2 == 1 && $j == $end)) ? " 2 ":"&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
            ($j == $end) ? $mid = false:"";
            ($rightCount > $leftCount) ? $right = true:$left = false;
            
            echo $line;
        }
        else if ($right)
        {
            $line = ($i % 2 == 0 && $j == $space) ? "&nbsp;&nbsp; ":" 3 ";

            ($j == $end) ? $mid = true:"";
            $rightCount = 0;
            $leftCount  = 1;

            echo $line;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

please need help to improve my code, so i can get print like first output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like a lot of code to do essentually 3 things, break it down.

- **Make a line which has one hole**

  - Pick the position where the hole will be `rand(1, max-1)`
  - Fill the rest with wall
- **On alternating lines there is no wall**

  - Fill all with empty space
- **Surround the outer wall**

  - Is it first or last

Join all lines/array and output.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$maze = [];
for($i=0; $i<=8; $i++) {
    $hole = rand(1, 6);
    $line = [];
    for ($ii=0; $ii<8; $ii++)
        $line[] = $ii === 0 || $ii === 7 ? '@' : ($ii === $hole || $i % 2 ? ' ' : '@');
    $maze[] = join($line).PHP_EOL;
}
echo join($maze);
```

**Output:**

```
@@@@@ @@
@      @
@@@ @@@@
@      @
@@@@@ @@
@      @
@@@ @@@@
@      @
@@@@@@ @
```

https://3v4l.org/XrWbE

Use `$hole = $i % 4 ? 6 : 1;` if you want holes to be in same place like your example.

```
@ @@@@@@
@      @
@@@@@@ @
@      @
@ @@@@@@
@      @
@@@@@@ @
@      @
@ @@@@@@
```

Edit:

Now changed to 5

https://3v4l.org/jTbeI

```
@ @@@
@   @
@@@ @
@   @
@ @@@
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for ur answer.. i already check the code but didnt dont want show in browser, i already update my question with that im trying right now. Maybe u have suggestion about it.

Comment: you have to wrap in a <pre> tag or use css `white-space: pre` :/ I've updated answer so you can easily change the size, so it should fit in the goal post now